# I can not draw on canvas with loaded image

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, html5-canvas

I can't draw an image on a canvas. I'm sure the image is loaded before drawing. 
Why I can't draw sprite if I know for sure the image is loaded?

The error is the following

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap)'
```

and an example code:

```
//Canvas
var canvas;
var ctx;
var sprite;

var load = function(){

    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = 400;
    canvas.height = 300;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    var spriteSheet = new Image();
    spriteSheet.onload = function(){
        initSprites(this);
        draw();
    };
    spriteSheet.src = "http://users.aber.ac.uk/jov2/sprite.png";
};

var draw = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(sprite,0,0);
}

var initSprites = function(img){
    sprite = new Sprite(img, 0,  0, 32, 32);
};

function Sprite(img, x, y, width, height) {
    this.img = img;
    this.x = x*2;
    this.y = y*2;
    this.width = width*2;
    this.height = height*2;
};
```

[Code](https://jsfiddle.net/yzvrs1re/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are trying to draw instance of Sprite not Image. Try this

```
var draw = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(sprite.img,0,0);
}
```